# Create a SQL View that Combines several M-M entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a data model that looks something like this:

Document has one to many Attributes
Document has one to many Properties

I'd like to create a view that brings in Document, Attributes, and Properties, but only one row per document. Typically a view like the above would yield one row per Document->Attribute and Document->Property accomplished with LEFT OUTER JOINs.

I'd like to combine all the attributes into a single "column" and properties into a single "column" like this:

Document 1, AttributeA Attribute B Attribute C, Property1 Property 2

Any pointers on how to gather those together?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DocSearch]
                AS
                SELECT  N.Id, N.CreatedBy, N.CreatedOn, N.ModifiedBy, N.ModifiedOn, N.DocumentContext, N.DocumentSource, 
                        N.DocumentText, N.DocumentType, N.Confidentiality, N.ExpirationDate, S.PropertyName, 
                        R.AttributeName, N.RowVersion
                FROM    dbo.Document AS N LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.DocumentProperty AS NS ON N.Id = NS.DocumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.Property AS S ON NS.PropertyId = S.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.DocumentAttribute AS NR ON N.Id = NR.DocumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.Attribute AS R ON NR.AttributeId = R.Id
```

Wanting to get Attributes and Properties together into one column each per Document.

Comment: you can use subqueries with STRING_AGG function to do this.

Comment: Okay, can you show me an example? Here's my current query (added to question)

Comment: For examples you might try looking at the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you - that did it!